# How to include PWA and React with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I was wondering is it possible to include PWA and React together with ASP.NET MVC. I have experience of working React and MVC together, but now I want to include PWA into the mix as well. Is the process just like how you put React into MVC, which just includes the files of PWA like manifest and service worker together with React and the other JS library and that's it or is there any other special way to do it. Thank you in advance!